# Unable to execute include files in PHP Application in Amazon Linux

Tags: php

I'm currently having problem solving why I can't execute inlclude files in my project folder. See **/var/logs/httpd/error_log** below:

Project folder resides at `/var/www/payroll`

> [Fri Jul 27 05:12:11.793208 2018] [:error] [pid 7904] [client xxx] PHP 
>       Warning:  include_once(./Controllers/Databasecon.php): failed to open stream: 
>       No such file or directory in /var/www/payroll/Controllers/Logout.php on line 
>       2
>
> [Fri Jul 27 05:12:11.793238 2018] [:error] [pid 7904] [client xxx] PHP 
>       Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening './Controllers/Databasecon.php' for 
>       inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in 
>       /var/www/payroll/Controllers/Logout.php on line 2

Configured App in VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName binhimefi.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
     <Directory /var/www>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you help me pont out the problem? Thanks.

Comment: by the way. I just currently uploaded php project to this server. PHP project runs good without issues before uploading to this Linux Server

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, for this project. I'm not using any framework.

Comment: are you including file inside Logout.php file ? If yes, then just include file Databasecon.php. Do not set Controllers folder location.

Comment: can you describe your app directory structure ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

you should define `BASE_PATH` that will always give you `/var/www/payroll/`

`include_once(./Controllers/Databasecon.php)` will try to include file from wrong directory `include_once(/var/www/payroll/Controllers/Controllers/Databasecon.php)`.

Instead, you should use `include_once(BASE_PATH + /Controllers/Databasecon.php)`